# Is AWS Account Number random or the numbers says some information?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I've couple of AWS Accounts. They all have a unique number. Just curious to know, are those account number random? Or is there any pattern in those number?

Some more details: I'm actually trying to understand when can all the AWS Account number be used?

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/acct-identifiers.html) says that;

> AWS assigns two unique IDs to each AWS account:
>
> - An AWS account ID
> - A canonical user ID

> An AWS account ID is a 12-digit number, such as 123456789012.

I don't think there is a pattern for this, the only "known" and "important" fact is that they are unique.

> I'm actually trying to understand when can all the AWS Account number be used?

Since it is 12 digits number i think there can be (10^11 * 9) different combinations (900.000.000.000) and it is a huge number, so it is fine.

Comment: I believe account numbers are sequential. My account from 10 years ago have lower numbers for the id than one issued today.

Comment: @RodrigoM we have 8 years old account and starts with 9, it can be sequential but if it is then didn’t start from 000000000001.